# Why is Disgaea 3 Absence of Detention asking for my location information?

Tags: ps-vita, disgaea-3

Right before starting Tutorial 3, my PS Vita asked me if I wanted to allow this game to access my location information.

Does anybody know what this information is used for in the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disagaea 3 grants you points for traveling places with your PS Vita.  Other games allow you to unlock artwork, specialty items or other unlocks based on how far you travel with you PS Vita (in terms of kilometers or miles), thus requiring location information to calculate this.  PS Vita also uses location information in apps like NEAR (to help find nearby PS Vita gamers) or Photos (to add location metadata to pictures).

Please view these links for further information:
http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/psvita/settings/location.html
http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/639534-disgaea-3-absence-of-detention/62616369

I hope this helps you!